# Why indexed view doesn't improve the performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am testing the performance of an indexed view. Below are the codes that I used.
I am using AdventureWorks2012 Database.

--Create test tables

```
 SELECT * 
    INTO Person.Person_Test
    FROM [Person].[Person]
    go
    SELECT * 
    INTO Person.PersonPhone_Test
    FROM [Person].[PersonPhone]
    go
    SELECT * 
    INTO Person.BusinessEntityAddress_Test
    FROM [Person].BusinessEntityAddress
    go
    SELECT * 
    INTO Person.Address_Test
    FROM [Person].Address
    go

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

--Create indexes on tables

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Person1 ON Person.Person_Test (BusinessEntityID);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX PersonPhone1 ON Person.PersonPhone_Test (BusinessEntityID);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX BusEntity1 ON Person.BusinessEntityAddress_Test (BusinessEntityID);
CREATE INDEX BusEntity2 ON Person.BusinessEntityAddress_Test (AddressId);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX AddressInd1 ON Person.Address_Test (AddressId);
```

--Create a view based on the four tables

```
 CREATE VIEW My_View WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
      SELECT P.BusinessEntityID,P.FirstName,P.LastName, PH.PhoneNumber,PH.PhoneNumberTypeID,BU.AddressID,AD.AddressLine1
      FROM Person.Person_Test P
      INNER JOIN Person.PersonPhone_Test PH
      ON P.BusinessEntityID=PH.BusinessEntityID
      INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress_Test BU
      ON P.BusinessEntityID=BU.BusinessEntityID
      INNER JOIN Person.Address_Test AD
      ON BU.AddressID=AD.AddressID
      WHERE P.BusinessEntityID BETWEEN 50 AND 10000 AND AD.AddressID BETWEEN 100 AND 1000
    GO
```

Then I test the performance without index (Query1)

```
--Test regular view 
SELECT BusinessEntityID,LastName,PhoneNumber,AddressID, AddressLine1
FROM My_View
WHERE BusinessEntityID between 50 and 200
```

The message I got is :

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 8 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(91 row(s) affected)
Table 'Address_Test'. Scan count 91, logical reads 185, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'PersonPhone_Test'. Scan count 91, logical reads 184, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Person_Test'. Scan count 91, logical reads 286, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'BusinessEntityAddress_Test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
```

Then I add index on the view

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_MyView ON My_View(BusinessEntityID);
go
```

However, I got the same message if I rerun the above Query 1.
I also attach the Execution plan here. Both the Execution plans are the same, no matter the view is indexed or not indexed. [image][image]

Is there something that I missed? Why the performance is the same after I add index to the view?

Comment: I say drop the indexes on table and do your test again. in your plan all operations are using index_seek. may SQL is using indexes on tables so it doesn't matter if you have index on view or not. remember that optimizer is very smart. anyway, you may get better answer if you post on dba site. http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: What version os sql-server? Standard or Enterprise? Consider running the query on the view with the queryhint NOEXPAND.

Comment: @mxix You are right. NOEXPAND gives me another message.

Comment: @FLICKER I think you are right. Optimizer may think it doesn't need to use the index in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view condition is more restrictive than the query condition. The view has less data than required.

```
WHERE P.BusinessEntityID BETWEEN 50 AND 10000 AND AD.AddressID BETWEEN 100 AND 1000
```

vs.

```
WHERE BusinessEntityID between 50 and 200
```

Even when that is fixed indexed view matching is very fragile and can fail. You might need to force it using `NOEXPAND`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@mxix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3665707/mxix). NOEXPAND gives me a new message.

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID,LastName,PhoneNumber,AddressID, AddressLine1
FROM My_View WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE BusinessEntityID between 50 and 200;
go
```

The message:

```
 SQL Server parse and compile time: 
       CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
    SQL Server parse and compile time: 
       CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(91 row(s) affected)
Table 'My_View'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

[image]
[@FLICKER](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017065/flicker) is also right that optimizer is very smart.

---

[@usr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr) points out the key point. If I use

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID,LastName,PhoneNumber,AddressID, AddressLine1
FROM My_View 
WHERE BusinessEntityID between 100 and 20000;
go
```

I don't need to specify NOEXPAND. SQL Server will use the index in view automatically.

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 15 ms, elapsed time = 16 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(129 row(s) affected)
Table 'My_View'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Comment: This is not a different query with different filters set.